# Contar datos Array

Tags: javascript, array

Necesito una forma de reducir un `array` y unificar y contar las coincidencias en una `matriz` nueva, esto son los datos:

Reducir un `array` de un `API`, convertirlos en una `matriz` y contar los nombres los países y dejar solo los países sin repetir y la cantidad de veces que aparecen repetidos

```
datos = [{"PaisExportador": "CHINA","fila": 1}, 
         {"PaisExportador": "URUGUAY","fila": 2},
         {"PaisExportador": "HONG KONG","fila": 3}, 
         {"PaisExportador": "CHINA","fila": 4}
        ];

matriz = [[{"nombre": "CHINA","cant": 2}],
          [{"nombre": "URUGUAY","cant": 1}],
          [{"nombre": "HONG KONG","cant": 1}]
         ]
```

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es traducir esos dos arrays en un JSON?

Comment: @Error404 lo que necesito es llevar datos a matriz, recibo un `array` de un `API` y necesito contar los nombres los países y dejar crear una matriz con los países sin repetir y la cantidad de veces que aparecen repetidos

Comment: ¿La API la puedes modificar? Creo que sería mucho mejor que devolvieras simplemente un array llamado "PaisExportador" con todos los elementos y lo mismo para "nombre". De esta manera, tendrías dos arrays simplemente con sus valores.

Comment: @Error404 no lo puedo modificar.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para contar los países puedes hacer un Loop. Luego usar un objeto como mapa para ir acumulando los valores.

```js
var datos = [{"PaisExportador": "CHINA","fila": 1}, 
         {"PaisExportador": "URUGUAY","fila": 2},
         {"PaisExportador": "HONG KONG","fila": 3}, 
         {"PaisExportador": "CHINA","fila": 4}
        ];

var matriz = {};

datos.forEach(function(registro) { 
  var pais = registro["PaisExportador"];
  matriz[pais] = matriz[pais] ? (matriz[pais] + 1) : 1;
});

console.log(matriz);
```

Luego si necesitas ese formato especifico que pones en la pregunta, puedes usar `map` para traducir de un formato al otro, como en este ejemplo:

```js
var datos = [{"PaisExportador": "CHINA","fila": 1}, 
         {"PaisExportador": "URUGUAY","fila": 2},
         {"PaisExportador": "HONG KONG","fila": 3}, 
         {"PaisExportador": "CHINA","fila": 4}
        ];

var matriz = {};

datos.forEach(function(registro) { 
  var pais = registro["PaisExportador"];
  matriz[pais] = matriz[pais] ? (matriz[pais] + 1) : 1;
});

// luego puedes usar la primera matriz, para crear el arreglo con tu formato necesitado.
matriz = Object.keys(matriz).map(function(pais) {
   return { nombre: pais, cant: matriz[pais] };
});
console.log(matriz);
```

Comment: La verdad que me ha intrigado tu respuesta ya que no sabía que se podía usar directamente un foreach en un array. ¿Que es lo que se supone que se pasa cuando pasas fila? ¿Un array con ambos valores asociativos ("PaisExportador" y "fila")?

Comment: @Error404 la `fila` es cada elemento del arreglo `datos` que son objetos. Ej `{"PaisExportador": "CHINA","fila": 1}` es un valo de `fila`.

Comment: @Error404 ahora me doy cuenta de que use `fila` y se confunde con la propiedad `fila` del objeto, pero es casualidad, `fila` se referia al registro del arreglo.

Comment: lo cambie por registro para mayor claridad.

Comment: Sí, realmente me confundió un poco por el hecho de que se llamaran igual. Ahora he entendido realmente lo que hace tu código. +1 sin duda, encima he aprendido algo nuevo ^^